# Strcat appends the whole structure instead of one element

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
char gpsTime[6];
char gpsStatus[1];
char gpsLat[10];
char gpsLong[10];
char gpsSpeed[5];
char gpsDate[6];
} gpsData;
```

and also a string at which I would like to concatenate the elements of this structure:

```
#define MESSAGESIZE 100
// Final message to be sent
char message[MESSAGESIZE]="$STARTOFMSG,23,";
```

The problem is, when I use "strcat" function like this:

```
strcat(message,data.gpsTime);
```

I expect to have something like this:

```
"$STARTOFMSG,23,083559";
```

but the total elements of structure are concatenated, i.e.:

```
"$STARTOFMSG,23,,083559A4717.1143700833.91520.004091202#@";
```

I guess this is a problem with pointers. How should I solve this?

Comment: Use strlcat. strcat runs to the first null character of the source operand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `gpsTime` is not properly terminated, i.e. it's not a valid C string. This will cause undefined behavior.

If you expect it to be `"083559"` as shown, it cannot be `char gpsTime[6]` since that leaves no room for the terminator. It has to be `char gpsTime[7]` or more. This of course goes for all of the strings; a C string with `n` characters has to have `n + 1` `chars` worth of space since the final one must be `\0` to terminate the string.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` copies the string up to the `/0` termination character. Add the termination char and it should work.

`083559` is already 6 character, so you need to define `gpsTime` as `char gpsTime[7]` and add the `/0` termination character.